# How to show 12 bit binary in four character hex string?

Tags: java, android

I am converting binary to hex. Below is the code.

```
public static String binaryToHex(String binary) {
    return String.format("%21X", Long.parseLong(binary,2)) ;
}
```

If I am giving the input: 111111111111.
getting output: FFF

But I want the output to be like this, 0FFF. How can I format it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you probably just want someone to tell you, but you should *really* take a look over Oracle's documentation for this. And maybe bookmark it (I have it bookmarked).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

(PS: I'd try %04X as my formatting string)